# Form Sends Results on Page Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a hidden div I am loading on click of submit button. The form is also sending results on the page load? I made sure I included validateForm() function and called it at the end of submit function with return validateForm(); It's also currently loading the hidden div and sending results as soon as I click submit. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$name = stripslashes($name);
$address = stripslashes($address);
$city = stripslashes($city);
$state = stripslashes($state);
$phone = stripslashes($phone);
$email = stripslashes($email);


$to  = 'info@thebrlab.com ' . ', ';
$to .= $Email; 

$from = "$Email ";
$subject = 'Look and Learn: Applicant'; 
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<b>Look and Learn: Applicant</b><br /><br />

<b>Name:</b> $name<br />
<b>Address:</b> $address / $city, $state<br />
<b>Phone:</b> $phone<br />
<b>Email:</b> $email<br />

</body>
</html>
EOF;
//end of message

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Razor Chic of Atlanta <info@thebrlab.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$to = "$to";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign-up.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function() {
$('#thankyou').show();
$("#hidden1").html($("#thankyou").html());
});
});

</script>

<script>

function validateForm()
{

var x=document.forms["myContact"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Your Full Name");
return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myContact"]["address"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Your Address");
return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myContact"]["city"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Your City");
return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myContact"]["phone"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Your Phone Number");
return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myContact"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Your Email");
return false;
}

}


$('#myContact').submit(function () {

$.each($('#myContact .notShouldBeBlank'), function()
{
if($(this).val() == ''){
$(this).after('<span class="error">This field is required.</span>');
return false;
}
});

return validateForm();
}
</script>


</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">



<div id="wrap">
<div id="hidden1"></div>
<div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
Sign-Up: Look And Learn Class
</div>

<br>

<form id="myContact" action="" name="myContact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<label>
<span>Name: *</span><br>
<input name="name" type="text" size="64" placeholder="Name">
</label>
</div>

<div>
<table width="100%" >

<tr>

<td width="230">
<label>
<span>Address: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Address" size="100" type="text" name="address" maxlength="100">
</label>
</td>

<td width="160">
<label>
<span>City *</span><br>
<input placeholder="City" name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="100" />
</label>
</td>

<td width="189">
<label>
<span>State *</span><br>
<input placeholder="State" name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="3" />
</label>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div>
<label>
<span>Phone: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Phone" size="64" type="text" name="phone">
</label>
</div>


<div>
<label>
<span>Email: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Email address" size="64" type="email" name="email">
</label>
</div>

<div>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">S  I  G  N    U  P</button>
</div>
</form>
<p>Note: * Fields are required</p>

</div>


<!---- THANK YOU---->
<?php
if($sent){

echo '<div id="thankyou" style="display:block;">';
}
else{
echo '<div id="thankyou" style="display:none;">';
}
?>


<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow1-wrapper">
<div id="paynow1">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@thebrlab.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Deposit">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->


<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow2-wrapper">
<div id="paynow2">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@thebrlab.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Balance">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->



<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow3-wrapper">
<div id="paynow3">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@thebrlab.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Full Payment">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="199.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->



<img src="images/thank-you/look-and-learn1.png" />

</div>
<!---- THANK YOU---->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone pleaseeeee help me and point out what's wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include my last comment in the original post. I'm fairly new to stack overflow Dagon….Thank you. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked, "The form is also sending results on the page load?", well if by that you mean on page load mail() is executing then you would be correct. The usual pattern is to test if some request variable is set, and only then call mail(), e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```